# How can I enforce Google SafeSearch on Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, google, firefox-for-android

I'd like to enforce Google SafeSearch on Firefox/Chrome on Android.

Is there any way to do it? For example, if I enable it and then switch to Incognito/Private mode the setting will disappear.

For desktop, there are extensions which enforce safesearch for google. I'd like to have the same behavior on Android.